# Sylvester–Gallai theorem with circle version, plane version and curve version?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, co.combinatorics, conjectures

The [Sylvester–Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) in geometry states that, given a finite number of points in the Euclidean plane, either

1. All the points are collinear; or
2. There is a line which contains exactly two of the points.

I think the theorem is also true for circle, plane version and curve version, can you give a proof of these versions?

**Conjecture: (circle version):**

> Given a finite number of points in the Euclidean plane, either
>
> 1. All the points are concyclic; or
> 2. There is a circle which contains exactly three points.

**Conjecture: (Plane version)**

> Given a finite number of points in the three-dimensional space, either
>
> 1. All the points in a plane; or
> 2. There is a plane which contains exactly three points.

**Conjecture: (Curve version)**

> Let $n, N$ be the natural number with $(\frac{3n+n^2}{2} < N < \infty)$, give $N$ points in the Euclidean plane,  either
>
> 1. All the points lie on a curve of degree $n$; or
> 2. There is a curve of degree $n$ which contains exactly $\frac{3n+n^2}{2}$ of the points.

Comment: Motzkin, The lines and planes connecting the points of a finite set, Trans Amer Math Soc 70 (1951) 451-464, MR0041447 (12, 849c), proved some generalizations of Sylvester-Gallai. I think both of your conjectures are there. Gupta, Non-concyclic sets of points, Proc Nat Inst Sci India 19 (1953) 315-316, MR0056941 (15, 149d) proved the circle conjecture, but the review by Blumenthal says it's already in the Motzkin paper.

Comment: See also Wiseman and Wilson, A Sylvester theorem for conic sections, Discrete Comput Geom 3 (1988) no. 4 295-305, MR0947218 (89f:52024).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plane version is false as stated. Choose two skew lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and place $\geq 3$ points on each of them. Any three of these points will either all lie on the same $\ell_i$ (and thus be collinear) or two of them will lie on the same $\ell_i$, so the plane they span contains that $\ell_i$ and thus contains three collinear points.

A true version is that there is a plane containing precisely $k$ of the points for which $k-1$ of them are collinear. This is due to [Motzkin](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1951-0041447-9) (Trans. AMS, 1951), with a higher dimensional generalization by [Hansen](https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10758) (Math. Scand. 1965). I took the above counterexample from Hansen's paper.

<strike>I think the curve version should be false, but I haven't broken it yet.</strike> I have now discovered two papers: [Wiseman and Wilson](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02187914), (Disc. and Comp. Geom 1988) and [Czapliński et. al.](https://doi.org/10.4171/rsmup/136-13), (Rendiconti del Seminario Matematico della Università di Padova 2016) which pose the curve version as an open question, so it probably isn't easy to resolve.

Comment: An earlier version of this answer claimed the opposite, and tried to reduce the problem to the SG-theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The error was that multiple points of the original configuration could become the same point in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 6):

For the circles part: it's true.

Assume that each circle defined by our set of points $S$ contains $\geq 4$ points; in particular, there are $\geq 4$ points in total. Fix one of them, say $p$, and consider all the circles determined by our points and passing through $p$; each such circle passes through $\geq3$ points from $S-\{p\}$.

Now apply inversion with center $p$ - under this, the above observation shows that $S-\{p\}$ goes to a set of points with the property that any line through two of them contains a third. Applying the standard version of the theorem, we see that all the images of $S-\{p\}$ under the inversion are collinear - hence, $S-\{p\}$ all lie on a circle through $p$.

Comment: For this argument, are you assuming that three collinear points define a "circle" (i.e., the line through the points)?

Comment: you kind of have to right? otherwise the original question is false too: e.g. if all the points are on a line

Comment: A line is special case of a circle, a line is a circle with radius equal $\infty$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82220/a-circle-with-infinite-radius-is-a-line